# google-cloud-vision API_DOCUMENT_TEXT bounding boxes in descending order

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Up until 9/21/2018, when I received a response from TextAnnotation response = client.DetectDocumentText(image);,  the bounding boxes for all, Pages,Blocks,Paragraphs and Words were in ascending order. Seems appropriate, we read from top to bottom. On the date previously mentioned, I started getting data that was in descending order. Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 2):

The order you indicate corresponds to the expected order for TextAnnotation: The hierarchy of an OCR extracted text structure is like this: TextAnnotation -> Page -> Block -> Paragraph -> Word -> Symbol . Each structural component, starting from Page, may further have their own properties. 
You may find related detail on the "Method: images.annotate" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#TextAnnotation). 
To have the issue examined and properly addressed, you are encouraged to open a similar issue in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).